# Did Gandhi say "The most violent weapon on earth is the table fork"?

Tags: quotes, mahatma-gandhi

Did Mahatma Gandhi say

> The most violent weapon on earth is the table fork.

Example of the quote as a heading image of the twitter account [@Cutwitts](http://www.donotlink.com/e3bm):

[image: Text included in quote above]

Comment: Seems like an odd thing for him to say, since a large percentage of people in the world don't eat with forks.

Comment: @user3169: And many who do eat with forks use them to eat their rice & vegetables.

Comment: [At least perhaps he knew what he was talking about](http://store.paulfrasercollectibles.com/Mahatma-Gandhi-bowl-fork-and-spoons-for-sale-p/pt783.htm)

Comment: Let us just call him Gandhi. There is no need to put Mahatma before it.

Comment: its a quote about the dangers of foreign cultural tenancies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In her book *[Animal Grace](https://books.google.com/books?id=jHl3AAAAMAAJ)* (first published in 2000) [Mary Lou Randour](https://www.facebook.com/mary.l.randour) writes:

> Gandhi noted the significance of eating utensils as symbols, saying that **the most violent weapon on earth is the knife** used at the dining table.

I can find no earlier use of the phrase "most violent weapon on earth", in any context. Note that Randour doesn't claim to be quoting Gandhi verbatim, and also does not indicate what source she might be paraphrasing from.

The exact quote, "The most violent weapon on earth is the table **fork**," seems to first appear in 2004, [The World Peace Diet by Will Tuttle,](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1590560833) and is attributed to Ghandi. Again no specific source is given.

Make of this what you will, but without any further evidence, the quote remains pretty suspect.

Answer (score 10):

This is no way meant to be a complete answer but I think it is a good starting point.
[Here](http://www.mkgandhi.org/bk123.htm) is a list of all(?) the books on and by M. K. Gandhi. I think it is quite a reliable website. You can easily find the PDF of most of these books online.

From the list, the two books, which are on the topic of vegetarianism (If that is the context he meant it in), are [The Moral Basis of Vegetarianism](http://www.mkgandhi.org/ebks/moralbasis_vegetarianism.pdf) and [Diet and Reform](http://www.mkgandhi.org/ebks/diet_and_diet_reform.pdf) (It is quite possible that I am looking at a strictly smaller subset). There is no mention of the word 'fork' in any of these two books. Maybe the quote was paraphrased? I just searched the PDF using Adobe.

It is entirely possible that the quote was verbal.